Best practice for discovering App Configuration endpoint?
Say I'm deploying a 12 Factor app in Azure and I'm storing all my configuration for said application in Azure App Configuration Service (AACS). In order to ensure proper isolation between stages, I'm hosting dev, integ, staging, and prod all in their own subscriptions, which means I'll have an AACS instance in each subscription with the environment config for that stage.
This is all great, until you realize that you've got a chicken and egg problem. Because AACS requires a unique name for each instance, and by 12 factor principles, you shouldn't code configuration into the code, we've got a bootstrapping/discovery problem for your app to find the AACS instance.
How do you all handle this issue?

Just treat it as any other endpoint or environment-specific setting: use configuration files (e.g. appsettings.json) .

Read this once-  Azure App Configuration best practices Can you try these 2 workaround and see- You can store the AACS endpoint as a secret in Azure Key Vault and then retrieve it in your application code using the Azure Key Vault SDK. Second option- use environment variables to store the AACS endpoint and configure your application to read the endpoint from the environment variable.

I see that containers, app service, and functions all have configurable ENV vars that you can manage via Bicep. My problem was with VMs, which don't.
In the end, I made use of a tag on the VM to contain the AACS endpoint. When the VM launches, my userdata script queries IMDS for the VMs tags, extracts the bootstrapping value and carries on from there.
